# creating user home directory

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I've a user account in a remote machine. but it doesn't have a home directory in that machine.
Is it possible to create a home directory without having root account details. If yes, how it can be done.

Comment: Do you have shell access? What does `echo $HOME` tell you? What do you get for the next to last field if you do `grep yourusername /etc/passwd`?

Comment: $HOME is "/home/joe" and for grep, I got "joe:x:1013:1015::/home/joe:/bin/sh"

Comment: Do you have write permission in `/home/joe`? If yes, you do already have a `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what, you will still need a directory where you can store your stuff (i.e. write permission and it is not being cleaned-up like `/tmp`).

If you have such a directory setting the environment variable `$HOME` to that path will already make a lot of programs treat it like a home directory. You can set that variable with

```
$ export HOME=/some/dir/
```

You could put above line in a shell script you execute after each login. In that file you should also start your shell in login mode or make it source your `.profile` files.